# css <hr class="divider"> responsive

Tags: css, html

Problem is about , it works great on desktop but on mobile fails....

```
 [http://jsfiddle.net/9vv914uL/][1]
```

i want to make this divider responsive... because it is working very well on higher resolutions , as you can see....

and bonus is to make words inside

---

tag in different colors...

this is css stylesheet:

```
.divider {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.divider hr {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:40%;

}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
```

this is

```
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;"class="divider">
<hr class="left" style="margin-top:12px;"/>BLUE RED<hr class="right" style="margin-top:12px;"/>
        </div>
```

I dont know what to say about this problem, this is just plain text. I must go back to the stars <3

:)

Comment: according to your percentage, BLUE RED should be 20% or less of the width in order for it not to break the floats. Wrap that in a 20% w div and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways that this can be handled that would work better for what you are trying to do. In my example, I am using both a heading element and an empty div. The text in the heading element can be expanded as much as you would like without needing to worry about available space, and the solution is responsive out of the box.

HTML

```
<h3 class="divider">
    <span>Title</span>
</h3>

<div class="divider">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divider {
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    height: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: visable;
}

.divider span {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 10%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6uux0cbn/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it like this rather than messing with floats:

```css
.divider {
    text-align: center;
}

.divider:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px; /* this value depends on the font size */
}

.divider > span {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"><span>BLUE RED</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:20px;"class="divider">
    <hr class="left" style="margin-top:12px;"/>

      <div class="title">BLUE RED</div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.divider {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    position:relative;
    height: 68px;
}

.div hr {

    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 888;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  top:15px;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: and how to color word "blue" at color:blue;? and color red in red?